# Form is not shown in html correctly

Tags: python, html, django

Form is not shown in html correctly.I wrote in search.html,

```
{% load static %}

<form action='/search/' method='POST>
  <table>
    {{ form.as_table }}
  </table>
  <input name="submit" type="Search" />
  {% csrf_token %}
</form>
```

in views.py

```
def search(request):
   form = SearchForm()
   if request.method == 'GET':
       return render_to_response(
           'search.html', {'form': form}, RequestContext(request))
   elif request.method == 'POST':
      form = SearchForm(request.POST)
      search_result = POST.objects.all()
      if form.is_valid():
          result = search_result.filter(Q(title__contains=form.cleaned_data['keyword']))
   return render_to_response('search.html',{'form':form, 'result':result})
```

When I access search method,search.html is shown as  strings like
[now search.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmKtX.png)

It is not From,so I really cannot understand why such a thing happens.No error happens but UserWarning: A  `{% csrf_token %}`was used in a template, but the context did not provide the value.  This is usually caused by not using `RequestContext`.
  "A `{% csrf_token %}` was used in a template, but the context " is shown in terminal.How should I fix this?What is wrong in my code?

Comment: You should use [`render()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#django.shortcuts.render) instead of `render_to_response()` and pass in the `request`. [`render_to_response()` is deprecated in Django 2.0](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#render-to-response).

Comment: When I wrote`return render_to_response(request,
           'search.html', {'form': form}, RequestContext(request))`,TemplateDoesNotExist exist error happens ,before search.html is shown so I think error is caused different point.

Comment: My initial comment was incorrect, so I updated it. The problem is that you're using the deprecated `render_to_response()`.

Comment: @Blurp I wrote `return render('search.html', {'form': form})`,but TemplateDoesNotExist at /app/search/
{'form': <SearchForm bound=False, valid=Unknown, fields=(keyword)>} error happens.Am I think ur message wrong?

Comment: Pass in the `request` as I suggested above and as stated in the docs.

Comment: @Blurp no error happens but now nothing is shown in browser.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the issue, but I think your input tag is wrong, it should be this:

```
 <input name="submit" type="Search">
```

As here : https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp